# Finding strings with alpha and numeric pattern

Tags: c#

Any idea what is the best way to check if a string contains a value with following pattern and extract that value:

> ana-aa-aaaa

Above `a` is Alpha and `n` is numeric.

Comment: You can with [`Regex`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: You should try something and come back when you get stuck.

Comment: It would make the question a lot more clear if you give an example of your data, like `a1b-cd-efgh`.  Are you wanting to match the whole string, or just pull out the numeric character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it with a simple regular expression:

```
 Regex.Match(value, @"\p{L}\d\p{L}-\p{L}{2}-\p{L}{4}")
```

This produces a [`Match` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which may or may not be a [success](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.success%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). Getting the value of a successful match will produce the desired substring.

Above, `\p{L}` matches a letter, `\d` matches a decimal digit, and `-` matches a dash. When followed by `{<number>}`, an expression requires a specific number of matches.

Comment: You should probably use `\p{Nd}` (Number, Decimal Digit) or `\d` in preference to `\p{N}`. The first two restricts the match to decimal digits; the latter matches...rather more than decimal digits: in addition ot `Nd`, it matches the categories `Nl` (Number, Letter) and `No` (Number, Other). "Number, Letter" matches things like roman numerals, cuneiform, runic, etc. See http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nl/list.htm for the complete list. "Number, Other" matches dingbats, fractions, Phoenician, etc. See http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/No/list.htm for the list.

Comment: @NicholasCarey Thanks for a correction, I changed the answer to use `\d`. Thank you!